# Is it OK for interfaces to depend on concrete classes?

Tags: java, design, object-oriented, interfaces

I am creating interface in Java for custom error handler.

Want to pass an argument error object but I need it to be child of `Exception` class.

Is it okay to use my defined class name in an interface ?

Won't it make it less of an interface in terms of not being dependent
on any implementation ?

I try to do something like this:

```
public class CustomException {
    /* ... Implementation ... */
}

public interface Interface {

    void onError(CustomException ex);

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to ask if it's okay to inherit another class in an interface?

Comment: @StevieV No. I edited the question, look.

Comment: I see now. There's no problem with having an interface and an exceptions in the same assembly. Because, how many different ways will you need to implement an exception? Probably not more than one way. You're doing right there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking specifically about custom exceptions, or is this merely an example? (BTW, your exception should probably extend `Exception` or one of its subclasses). Once you've clarified this, your question will probably be off-topic here and more on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @AndresF. It's just an example and can be applied to any OO language about using classes in interfaces.

Comment: Ok. So your question is about using concrete classes in your interfaces? How is using `CustomException` any different than using `String` as an argument to `onError`?

Comment: @AndresF. Well, you can change `CustomException` to have other dependencies as well. It's not guaranteed to be as safe as `String`. But I get it, It only must contain globally independent data.

Comment: Tell me: is `CustomException` part of the implementation or part of the interface?

Comment: @nikachx I don't understand what you mean by "safe". In what ways is `String` safer than `CustomException`? Why does it matter if `CustomException`, in turn, has other dependencies?

Comment: @immibis Hmm... It must be part of the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** I have to point out the fact that `CustomException` doesn't extend `Exception` so it is not really an `Exception`.

**That said:**

If you don't care about [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), then leave it as it is. **It's perfectly OK** for an interface to depend on concrete classes, for example **many interfaces depend on `String` or `Object` which are concrete classes**. The thing is that we would tend to believe that classes that belong to the Java SDK are more stable (less prone to code-breaking changes) than the ones we write.

**In the other hand:**

If you want to follow the DIP (which has countless benefits and is my recommendation), then you have to do one of two things:

**Option 1**

- Make `CustomException` abstract
- Keep `void onError(CustomException ex)` as it is

**Option 2**

- Make `CustomException` an interface
- Keep `void onError(CustomException ex)` as it is

With either of those options you would be conforming to the DIP, since the interface would not depend on any concrete class, only on abstractions.

> In a direct application of dependency inversion, the abstracts are
>   owned by the upper/policy layers. This architecture groups the
>   higher/policy components and the abstracts that define lower services
>   together in the same package. The lower-level layers are created by
>   inheritance/implementation of these **abstract classes or interfaces**.
>   Martin, Robert C. (2003).
>
> - Agile Software Development, Principles, > Patterns, and Practices. Prentice Hall. pp. 127–131. ISBN
>     978-0135974445.

Comment: There's not much difference between accepting an abstract class or a concrete (non-final) class, and the difference to an interface is not much more than that. As long as the instance is passed as a parameter and not hard-coded in your implementation, you have the foundations for DI.

Comment: @JacobRaihle What do you mean by passing an instance hard-coded in the implementation?

Comment: I said "as long as it is passed *and not* hard-coded". What I mean is that since the `Interface` interface accepts a `CustomException` and leaves it up to the caller to provide one, the caller is free to provide any class that extends `CustomException` even if `CustomException` is a concrete class - which would not have been possible if `Interface` was somehow responsible for creating it. This inversion of control, moreso than working with interfaces (although that certainly helps), is what I think DI is all about.

Comment: @JacobRaihle _"In a direct application of dependency inversion, the abstracts are owned by the upper/policy layers. This architecture groups the higher/policy components and the abstracts that define lower services together in the same package. The lower-level layers are created by inheritance/implementation of these **abstract classes or interfaces**."_ Martin, Robert C. (2003). Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices. Prentice Hall. pp. 127–131. ISBN 978-0135974445.

Comment: What is the point of an abstract class if you can provide a reasonable default? What do you *lose* by providing that? Don't just quote books, think.

Comment: @JacobRaihle _"What do you lose by providing that?"_ You create coupling.

Comment: If the concrete exception belongs to the same "policy level" than the interface. Are you coupling?

Comment: @Laiv Define _"policy level"_.

Comment: You have quoted a book paragraph where it does mention to higher and lower levels (of policies). If the abstraction and the concrete class belongs to the same "level" I assume there's no coupling

Answer (score 2):

Tulains is right - interfaces depend on concrete classes all the time. They are only meant to create a contract for their own concerns. That contract can involve taking and returning any kind of data.

Remember that in higher level languages, even primitive types are not so primitive. So you're working with concrete types anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by *name*, you mean the actual class itself. If you are trying to specify the actual exception class *name* in order to initialize the corresponding exception through Reflection, this is not the right way to go.

If you want to use a custom class in an interface, you can, of course, use your own classes in your own interfaces. The classes become parts of the public interface of your library/API. Data structures and exceptions are a good example of the classes which are often used by the interfaces.

If you need to use different exceptions depending on the context, then you may be interested in using generics.

Comment: No I don't mean reflection. Yes as you mention Exceptions and data structures can be used in interfaces because they just contain data and are not platform or otherwise dependent on other classes. Thank you.

Comment: Answers that ask the OP questions... Just ask in a comment, then provide your answer.

Comment: @StevieV: The first paragraph was more a rhetorical question. And as shown by the comment of the OP, I actually answered the OP's question.